# How do I wordwrap a dynamically edited TextBlock in Powershell with xaml?

Tags: powershell, xaml

I have managed to (almost) successfully create an about box using powershell with xaml. The (hopefully!) last thing I am stuck on is the TextBlock. My goal is to make a universal about.xml that can then be edited by each script that uses it (this prevents having dozens of about.xml). I have the "description" in a textBlock, but it loses the wordwrap feature when it is edited. Is there a way to preserve wordWrapping and font style when a text block is edited via powershell script? Note: I use Visual Studio Code with Notepad++. I don't have access to Visual Studio, and I am not authorized to use addons or other editors. I also don't want to use a RichTextBox, because I don't want the end user making any edits. I have been researching this all day, and none of the answers I have found online work. My codes are below. For my attempted edit, see the lines with "$editedBlock..."

Powershell script:

```
#First, add the assembly into the current session
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

#read xml file for about box 
$aboutXaml = "F:\aboutWindow.xml"
$global:aboutWindow = New-Object xml
$global:aboutWindow.Load($aboutXaml)

#create Xaml reader 
   $aboutReader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $aboutWindow)
   $aboutBox = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($aboutReader)

   $editedBlock = $aboutBox.FindName("editedTextBlock")
   $editedBlock.Text = "This text has been edited by the Powershell script. As you can
   see, the text wrap feature has been broken by this. It wraps, but also includes the 
   carriage return. 
   This makes it useless for the purpose of creating a dynamic about 
   xml that can be edited by the multiple scripts that will use it. It also strips 
   my font size/styles"
 #  $editedBlock.TextWrapping = "WrapWithOverflow" #These both appear to be useless....
   $editedBlock.TextWrapping = "Wrap" 
#aboutBox properties
   $aboutBox.Width="400"
   $aboutBox.Height="400"
   $aboutBox.Title="About"
   $aboutBox.Topmost="true"
   $aboutBox.ResizeMode="NoResize"
   $aboutBox.Icon = "my\icon\path"   
   $aboutBox.WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
   
   $aboutBox.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

My xml script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp9"> 

<Grid x:Name="Grid"
      Margin="10,10,10,10" >
   
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

<!-- Begin About Properties -->    
   <TextBlock Width="Auto"
              Margin="5,5,5,5"
              Grid.Row="0"
              TextWrapping="Wrap"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left">
      <Run Foreground="Transparent">IND.. </Run> 
      <Run FontFamily="Calibri" 
           FontSize="14"> Using TextBlock allows the use of Textwrapping, but 
           if they are dynamically edited, the text wrapping goes away. 
           The text I write is wrapped until that happens. Even
           if I hit enter in the 
           middle
           of a sentence, it wraps correctly</Run>
   </TextBlock>
   
   <TextBlock Width="Auto"
             Margin="5,5,5,5"
             Grid.Row="1"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             x:Name="editedTextBlock" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap">
      <Run Foreground="Transparent">IND.. </Run> 
      <Run FontFamily="Calibri" 
           FontSize="20"> place holder</Run>
   </TextBlock>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

The included image is the window that comes up.
[image: about window]

Comment: In the script do not try to make it look pretty and add line breaks.  Just let the text run off to the right.  Or if you don't like that you can use a StringBuilder object to build the string in parts.  Or, if you do add the line breaks in the script, remove the line breaks using replace `$Text = "Text with line breaks ..." -replace "\r?\n"`

Comment: That worked great! I actually really hate loooong lines of code with no line breaks, so I prefer this. I even found how to reset my font styles - manually in the PS script. Thanks!